# Analysis Maximizing value of I

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $B ∈ C([0,1],R)$ be closed, bounded, and equicontinuous.  Let $I:B→R$ be defined by $$I(f)=\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$$ Show that there is an $f_0 ∈ B$ at which the value of $I$ is maximized.

Okay so I am assuming the question is not asking to find the specific value, but to show that one exists.  Since B is equicontinuous,bounded, and closed would that imply that I(f) is continuous, bounded, and closed? Then you could say since it is these three things there exists a supremum and therefore I can be maximized.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Use Arzela-Ascoli theorem to show that $B$ is ...
- Recall that any continuous function on ... set attains maximum